# Adobe Sign OAuth Flow Error: Security Violation at /oauth/token

Tags: adobe, adobe-sign

I am trying to integration with Adobe Sign and the first step is getting an access token via OAuth2.0 flow. This is not my first time for SSO integration and OAuth flow and I am pretty familiar with Authorization Code Flow. However, I can't really get what problem I have is.

I opened an developer account and created an app and configure redirect uri and permissions. Using Postman I launched the authentication flow that I am able to see crendential challenge and permission consent screens, and finally issue a code to exchange with access token.

[Credential Challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quyb2.png)
[Permission Consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gptXt.png)

All of that were good until I exchange the code with access code. According to Adobe Sign documentation, it should return JSON with access_token and refresh token. I followed this [video](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/document-services/tutorials/acrobatsign/oem/generating-an-access-token.html?lang=en) with Postman to simulate the flow. The problem is that I am getting 200 Success response with an HTML instead of JSON. When I render the HTML, it saids `Error: Request Security Violation at /oauth/token`.
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00WN7.png)

I am not sure if this is common as my account is a developer account or anyone knows how to resolve this issue. I used the below fields to exchange with access_token

```
code=<authorization code>
grant_type=authorization_code
client_id=<account client id>
client_secret=<account client secret>
redirect_uri=<redirect uri set in the account>
```

Auth challenge URL: https://secure.na3.adobesign.com/public/oauth/v2
Token exchange URL: https://secure.na3.adobesign.com/public/oauth/v2/token

Help!

I tried various domain to go through flow as adobe is pretty vague on what domain to hit. Here are domains I tried.

```
secure.echosign.com
secure.na3.echosign.com
secure.na1.adobesign.com
secure.na2.adobesign.com
secure.na3.adobesign.com
```

Also, I sent an email to signembed@adobe.com that I got an reply back to ask the question to Adobe Support website which I did.